# Area formula for $n$-gon

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a formula for the area of a general polytope with $n$ vertices which just uses the distances between vertices, like Herons formel for the area of a triangle?

Comment: Regular polygons or any polygon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, the area of an $n$-gon cannot be deduced from the distances between vertices alone.  For example, the two $8$-gons

[image: n-gons with different areas]

have the vertices in the same places (and thus the distances between vertices will be the same), but will have different areas.

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions polytopes, so you could be asking whether Heron's formula generalizes to higher $n$-dimensional simplices.  For such a simplex, every pair of points is connected by an edge, and unlike the context of Rebecca's answer, the resulting shape is uniquely determined by all of these distances.  There is indeed a more general formula, given quite elegantly by [Cayley-Menger determinants](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html).